Duplicating data in my timeseries for my facebook model Prophet
I am working on fitting a Prophet model to my timeseries that shows the sales daily. The aim is to get a precise trend and find places where there is a change. My timeseries starts in September 2021 and ends in May 2024. However I'd like my model to fit best the period between November 2023 and May 2024, because it is the period I want to analyze precisely.
(Btw I have already managed seasonality and it seems to have learnt it well)
For this reason, I wanted to add weights to the data in the most recent period, but Prophet doesn't seem to accept weight. As a consequence I duplicated my data like so :
recent_df = df[df['ds'] >= '2023-11-01']
duplicated_data = pd.concat([recent_df] * 10, ignore_index=True)

# Combine duplicated data with original data
augmented_df = pd.concat([df, duplicated_data], ignore_index=True)

I'd like to know if this method works with Prophet? And if yes, how does it work? How does Prophet manage multiple times the same date?
